# potential memory issue with dynamically injecting jquery html() that has scripts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following pseudo-SPA like structure:

**HTML layouts example**

`main.html`

```
<html>
    <!--main content above...-->
    <!--dynamic content to replace following div...-->
    <div id="target"></div>
    
    <button onclick="replaceHtml('/sample/fragmentA')">fragmentA</button>
    <button onclick="replaceHtml('/sample/fragmentB')">fragmentB</button>
    <button onclick="replaceHtml('/sample/fragmentC')">fragmentC</button>

</html>
<script>
function replaceHtml(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:url
        , success: function(data){
            $("#target").html(data);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

`fragmentA.html`

```
<div>
    <!--some content to replace target...-->
</div>
<script>
var a = "a";
function somefunction_a(){
    //do something in a...
}
</script>
```

`fragmentB.html`

```
<div>
    <!--some content to replace target...-->
</div>
<script>
var b = "b";
function somefunction_b(){
    //do something in b...
}
</script>
```

**Requirements**

- all `fragmentsX.html` are dynamic pages that needs to be rendered by the server e.g. execute service, access DB etc
- all `fragmentsX.html` have `<script>` that has variables and functions specific to that fragment.
- there are at least a dozen of `fragmentsX.html` and more could be added in the future
- I am under **STRONG** requirement to keep `main.html` as the **base page** and load dynamic fragments into it as opposed to loading individual `fragmentsX.html` that *include* portion of the main.html

**Question**

- after `main.html` is loaded, when I access `fragmentsA.html` then move onto `fragmentsB.html`, I can still access all the variables and functions from the previous fragments (I'm assuming because they get loaded into memory once executed by jquery's `html()` and are not released since it's the same *"page"*)
- so my **question is** this:

1. if users continue to load fragments into `main.html` (which they will), wouldn't the client-side be flooded with variables and functions that are possibly no longer used but are not released from the memory? - maybe slowing down client-side rendering or allowing memory leak in return?
2. and if so, is there a way to release the variables and functions created by `html()` from memory before a new fragment is loaded?(while keeping vars and functions in `main.html`)

- only solution I can come up with is creating a wrapper object at `main.html` like so: `var fragmentsVars = {}` and attach variables from fragments to this `fragmentsVars.a = "a"` and emptying this variable after ajax complete: `...,complete(){fragmentsVars = {}}`
- but this solution would require all the fragment page developers to conform to this rule of creating vars and functions by appending to `fragmentsVars` and I don't think this is practically possible in the long run (human error).
- FYI, I'm using JS, thymeleaf for front-end and Java, Spring Boot for back-end
- I don't think I can use thymeleaf's `fragments` since all the fragments are dynamically loaded from user action and must be rendered server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin here's a test page to get a handle on some of the issues (modify as desired and test in a browser to get details of `document.scripts`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>$fragTest</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Target:
<div id="target"></div>
<hr>
<button type="button" onclick="loadFragA()">frag a</button><button type="button" onclick="loadFragB()">frag b</button>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>

<script text/javascript>"use strict";
function loadFragA(){

let html = 'FragmentA\n<script>\nvar a = "a";\nfunction something_a() {\n   alert("something_a()");\n}\n<\/script>\n';
$("#target").html(html);
}

function loadFragB(){
let html = 'FragmentB\n<script>\nvar a = "b";\nfunction something_b() {\n   alert("something_b()");\n}\n<\/script>\n';
$("#target").html(html);
}

function test() {
   console.log( "typeof a: %s, a: '%s': typeof something_a: %s, typeof something_b: %s, doc.scripts: ",
    typeof a, typeof a == "undefined" ? "undefined" : a,
    typeof b, typeof b == "undefined" ? "undefined" : b,
    typeof something_a, typeof something_b, document.scripts)
}
</script></body></html>
```

---

1. Running the test immediately demonstrates that the functions and global variables remain in place. If redeclared (like `var a = 'b';` in `fragmentB`) the new declaration replaces the old.

   - you can't declare global variables using `let` or `const` or `class` in fragments because reloading the fragment will attempt to redefine the identifier after the keyword which is not permitted.
2. Global variables are global. `main.html` should define what individual variables or a name space object that are **reserved** for inter-fragment communication, and provide a set of API endpoints that `main` provides for fragment use.

   - Fragments should be required to declare fragment variables in function scope, meaning in an IEFE or in a function that gets called when the fragment is loaded (more on this below).

---

Using the test code above showed that the number of script elements in the DOM did not go up as jQuery loaded new fragments or reloaded one previously loaded (in version 3.6.0 at least). Without looking into what jQuery is doing, to me this means you don't have to take care of removing script elements declared in fragments.

Regarding the choice between using an anonymous immediately executed function to perform set up in a fragment, the **alternative would be to use the same setup function name in each fragment** and call it after loading the fragment. During fragment load, the new version of the named setup function replaces the old function because JavaScript allows functions to be re-declared. Any function scope variables in the old setup function object will get garbage collected from memory.

If you implement a named setup function called from `main.html`, then you might as well implement a corresponding destroy function that can be called immediately before fragment replacement.

---

### Design Concept of a `main.html` API

This outline should be read as details of a concept, not a directive to adopt the concept or its rules without further research or appropriate consideration:

1. Fragment code must NOT create global variables.
2. `main.html` exposes whatever API methods or data it provides in global scope, such as `replaceHTML` and possibly a variable named `destroyFragment`;
3. `main.html` also provides a namespace object for inter fragment communication called, say, `fragmentNS`, which it does not monitor.
4. Fragments should create a single function named `setupFragment` (or similar) to be called after the fragment is loaded. This function contains all fragment code and variables.
5. Fragment code may set  global variable `destroyFragment` (or similar) to get called for cleanup before the fragment is replaced.
6. `replaceHTML` gets expanded to

- Call `destroyFragment` if it is a function,
- Set global variable `destroyFragment` to null,
- load the fragment html using the ajax call,
- in the `success` handler add a new line to call `setupFragment`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It is much in-depth than I asked for and I'm grateful. Will definitely try to implement these concepts using your sample code. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a followup question regarding  your answer: you mentioned a destroying function or variable - how would it be implemented? scan all variables in scripts and set to null?

Comment: @ChanyoungJoo - The purpose of `destroyFragment` is to provide an optional call back that performs cleanup before closing. Similiar to a destroying a class instance in other languages or responding to `onbeforeunload` events in HTML. As an option, fragment code can set up a callback by assigning the callback function to `destroyFragment`. Call the global variable `onTargetUnload` (or whatever you choose) if it makes things clearer. As an API, `main.html` doesn't care what the callback does - but you could use the return value to cancel HTML replacement if you want to go that far.